# A Python numpy array is being rewritten in a loop - shouldn't be doing this

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Using Anaconda, I have written a simple code and I am at wit's end trying to figure out how an array keeps getting rewritten in a for loop after it's defined. I write the array (random 0 or 1s) named ***box*** and define a new array ***holder*** as a "copy" of the array I want to leave alone. However, box keeps getting rewritten and I just don't see how it should be doing this.

```
#FUNCTIONS

def initialize():
    config = np.zeros([n, n])
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            if np.random.rand() < p:
                config[x, y] = 1
    return config

def roller(x):
    test1 = np.roll(x,1,axis=0)
    test2 = np.roll(x,1,axis=1)
    test3 = np.roll(x,-1,axis=1)
    test4 = np.roll(x,-1,axis=0)
    hold = np.sum([test1,test2,test3,test4],axis=0)
    return hold

def loop(steps,holder,store_config):
    for t in range(steps):
        tot = roller(holder)
        for x in range(n):
            for y in range(n):
                if tot[x,y] >= 4:
                    holder[x,y] = 1
                else: 
                    holder[x,y] = 0
        store_config[:,:,t] = holder

def func():
    start = time.time()
    time_steps = 20
    store_config = np.zeros([n,n,time_steps])
    loop(time_steps,holder,store_config)
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start, np.sum(store_config))

#CONSTANTS

n = 100
p = .2
box = initialize() #Array to leave ALONE
print(np.sum(box))

#Action
holder = box #Array to manipulate and redefine as box
func()
print(np.sum(box))
```

If you the value from the output of np.sum(box) should match before and after func() is ran , but they never do. The intention was that when I rerun func(), it spits out a value, but just iterates over the same defined "box" array but it keeps getting rewritten. I don't see how its possible. I thought arrays were treated like variables inside a function where they're not global? Each of the three sections #Functions, #Constants, and #Action would be in their own cells in a Conda Notebook.

Comment: I see `holder[x,y] = 1`, `holder[x,y] = 0` in your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you are having is that arrays, just as lists and dicts, are assigned by reference.  This happens no matter if it's a variable assignment or as an argument being passed to a function.

```
def f(x):
    x[0] = 0
    return x

a = array([1, 1])
b = f(a)
```

WILL result in `a` and `b` being equal, since `x` is being manipulated and then returned.  If you want to retain `a`, you must copy the array first:

```
def f(x):
    x_ = x.copy()
    x_[0] = 0
    return x_
```

I hope this clarifies things a bit. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The line `holder = box` doesn't create a new copy of the array, it causes `holder` to point to the same array as `box`. Since your code modifies `holder`, you want to make `holder` point to a copy of `box` so that it doesn't get overwritten. You can do this using [`np.copy()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) as in:

```
holder = np.copy(box)
```